# How to join and sum using SQL

Tags: sql, join

I got three tables that I'm trying to join together. My goal is to see of each order, its `orderdate`, `orderid`, `customer` and the `total amount of delivered items`. Each unique item in a order get a separate line in the order details table which means that I need to sum the total amount in my join but I don't know how?

```
    SELECT Orders.OrderDate
        , Orders.OrderID
        , Customers.CustomerName
        , OrderDetails.Quantity AS "Deliverd products"

    FROM Orders INNER JOIN Customers ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN Orderdetails ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
    ORDER BY CustomerName;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
SELECT Orders.OrderDate,
       Orders.OrderID,
       Customers.CustomerName,
       SUM(OrderDetails.Quantity) AS "Deliverd products"
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Orderdetails ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
GROUP BY Orders.OrderDate,
       Orders.OrderID,
       Customers.CustomerName
ORDER BY CustomerName;
```

Comment: It worked, is there a reason why you are grouping on OrderDate and CustomerName? I just grouped on OrderID.

Comment: You have to group all columns that used in select except used in the aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [Sum Over option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql) where you do not need group by explicitly

```
declare @orders table(orderid int identity (1,1), orderdate datetime, customerid int)
declare @orderdetails table(orderdetailsid int identity (1,1), orderid int, quantity int)
declare @customers table(customerid int identity (1,1), customername varchar(100))

insert into @orders values('2017-11-21' , 1)
insert into @orderdetails values (1,20) ,(1,5) , (1,7)
insert into @customers values('ajay')


SELECT distinct o.OrderDate,
       o.OrderID,
       c.CustomerName

       SUM(od.Quantity) OVER (ORDER BY od.OrderID) 
FROM @orders o
INNER JOIN @customers c ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
INNER JOIN @orderdetails od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID

ORDER BY CustomerName;
```